# Touchesbegan updating each frame

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch, touchesbegan

I am making a game where there is a button: while the button is pressed(touched), the player moves forward. When the button is released, the player stops moving.

Now I can do this with the touchesbegan and touchesended functions but that is not what I want since I am going to add more buttons and enable multitouch, there must be an easier way..

Anyone knows how?

Comment: You need to get the location of the touch, with the location you can decide what button the user pressed, tap or hold

Comment: How do I get the location from the override update function? And does this work with multiple touch?

Comment: Have a look in this tutorial, hope it helps you http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_Swift_iOS_8_Touch,_Multitouch_and_Tap_Application

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't help me. I need to know how to get the location of the touch from the update method.

Comment: Yes... It does help you... touchesBegan and touchesEnded updates every frame just like update would

Comment: @sdd - You cannot get a touch location from the update method. That's what the touches methods are for. If you need the touch location FOR USE in the update method, store them in variables.

Answer (score 0):

How to retrieve the touch location in swift

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInView(self)
}
```

You can do the same for all the other functions

Comment: Please give an example of a function called from the update that gets the location each frame

Comment: what do you mean? Just add it in the update part of your app and it will be called for each frame

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for Objective-C, *although being familiar with frames, locations on screen, layer properties etc is highly recommended as this solution detects coincidences between the user's touch and the location of the elements in the screen* (I'm talking about portrait, landscape... animations, etc).
Hope it helps.

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

  ```
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(aViewForExample.frame, touchLocation)){
       //the user has touched within this element, so what's next?
  }
  ```

  }